# YouTube Data Analytics - Get analytics of YouTube channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

just wondering if there is a way I could try and get the analytics of a channel in youtube. I can handily get the stats for the videos and the playlists but there is no api explorer for the youtube channel that allows me to select filters such as those countries that have viewed my videos, how many views my videos have per month and so on. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the YouTube Analytics API :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

Here is the link towards API explorer,
http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query